# TypeScript: Incorrect type inferring

Tags: typescript, types, boolean

The following code has the error "Variable 'b' is used before being assigned.(2454)":

```js
let b: boolean
function f () {
    b = true
}
f()
console.log(b)
```

Similarly,

```js
let b: boolean = false
function f () {
    b = true
}
f()
console.log(b === true ? "True" : "False")
```

gives the error: "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'false' and 'true' have no overlap.(2367)".

Of course, this prints True.

Is this a bug or the result of a bad practice? What's the best alternative?

Edit: so far, the best workaround I've found for the second issue is to do `let b = false as boolean` so that the type of `b` is boolean. And use `b!` for the first issue.

Comment: If you're wondering: using a function or an arrow function doesn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the compiler. I guess you could do `(b as boolean) === true`, refactor your code so the closures don't change outer scoped variables, or wrap `b` in an object.

Comment: I can also do `let b = false as boolean` actually.

Comment: Looks like this comes down to some potentionally intentional trade-offs in made in tsc going back at least a few years https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998